# BUG in lib dispatch appears in the system log

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

When the application that I'm developing is launched, a message appears and I don't understand why. The first message is managed by the application and appears in it's own log. The second message appears in the system log. What does this message mean ? I don't use Grand Central Dispatch in my project under Xcode 5.

```
09/11/13 12:19:44,095 MyApp[180]: MyApp v 1.1 launched

09/11/13 12:19:44,240 MyApp[180]: BUG in libdispatch: 12F45 - 1513 - 0x610b
```